# Transaction Scope Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2012, transactionscope

I am working on a Windows Application and executing a transaction on database on Sql Server 2005 through it.
I applied Transaction Scope around my transaction.
It gave me some error which i resolved using the below link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7172223f-acbe-4472-8cdf-feec80fd2e64/the-partner-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remotenetwork-transactions?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Although it works but i have to do this on each and every server machine where i have to run this code. My aim is to make it automated. What can i add in my code or what should be a way to enable my server to get through this? Advise.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

- Upgrade to not totally outdated technology - since IIRC WIndows 7 there is a micro Transaction Manager in the kernel that can handle "one transaction ressource only" scenarios. Any decent modern server would support that. Note that IIRC that is irrelevant to SQL 2005 - this is a pure client side change. Any decent modern server should support that.
- Make this change in your installer. It is not exactly super hard to make.

Generally thee is not a lot you can do to fix badly configured machines automagically.

Now, if you manage multiple connections to the same database (in one transaction) - then you basically have a serious programming mistake (reuse connections) and that forces the transaction monitor to go network without real need (just reuse one connection) and with serious performance implications.

Comment: We are using only one database connection but different functions to save different information in same database. I want to know code to automate MSDTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) settings.